# Expressing common vector operations in terms of quaternions

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-analysis, quaternions

Since everything we do with vectors could also in theory be expressed using quaternions (or octonions & higher-order -nions), is it possible to have common vector operations like the cross product or the dot product expressed in terms of quaternions? How are they called and what would they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you express* two vectors $v_1,v_2$ from $\mathbb R^3$ as quaternions $q_1,q_2$ with real part $0$, then the real part of $q_1q_2$ is $-v_1\cdot v_2$ and the pure quaternions part is $v_1\times v_2$.

This follows from the formula 
$$
(r_1,\ \vec{v}_1) (r_2,\ \vec{v}_2) = (r_1 r_2 - \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2,\ r_1\vec{v}_2+r_2\vec{v}_1 + \vec{v}_1\times\vec{v}_2)
$$
as given for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Scalar_and_vector_parts).

So they are both encoded:
$v_1\cdot v_2=-\text{RealPart}(q_1q_2)$

$v_1\times v_2=\text{PureQuaternionPart}(q_1q_2)$

where the real part of $a+bi+cj+dk$ is $a$ and the pure quaternion part is $(b,c,d)$.

---

(*) Concretely, if $v=(b,c,d)$, the quaternion representing it is $bi+cj+dk$.

Comment: More generally, $(r_1+v_1)(r_2+v_2)=r_3+v_3$ with $r_3=r_1r_2-v_1\cdot v_2,\,v_3=r_1v_2+r_2v_1+v_1\times v_2$.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, thanks for the edit. The phone screws up the single letter variables sometimes...

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! So I just multiply them together without doing any fancy stuff?

Comment: @MaxMustermann The fanciest thing you have to do is negate the real part :/

Comment: Great, thanks, thats suprisingly easy. After seeing the derivation for the formula of the cross product, I thought it was a rather hard problem and didn't have the courage to try and solve it myself. Interresting, how our mind sometimes makes problems harder than they are. Anyway, thank you for your answer, I searched the internet and didnt find anything. Thanks :D

Comment: @MaxMustermann Yes, it is one of those miraculous truths.

Comment: Hi, I just thought about how strange it is that multiplying complex numbers corresponds to a rotation and multiplying  quaternions corresponds to the cross product and stumbled across [this](https://eater.net/quaternions/video/intro), if you happen to have time, do yourself a favor and play arround with it. It truely is awesome and gives a deeper understanding about the beauty of quaternions. : )

Comment: @MaxMustermann Historically speaking, one of the ancestors of the dot and cross products is quaternion multiplication.

Comment: @amd The cross product of vectors seems quite inelegant compared to the ones of quaternions. Seeing this arise in quaternion multiplication so easily must be one of the most beautiful things I have experienced in math. I can't imagine why we would use vectors over quaternions, vectors seem blunt compared to them. When quaternions had even been there before vectors, why do we use and teach vectors today?

Comment: @MaxMustermann Because Gibbs won the battle against Hamilton in the vectors-versus-quaternions war that happened 130 years ago.  There are discussions of how this happened all over the place. [Here is one article I haven't read yet but probably will.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00501.pdf) The struggle even got ugly and personal in publications in a way which I think befits physicists more than mathematicians.

Comment: @MaxMustermann There is nothing wrong with vector algebra. I do think that it suits most audiences better than the quaternion version. I think the quaternion version is a beautiful enrichment, but not a wholly complete replacement.  It is important NOT to become a cheerleader for quaternions just because it is historically an underdog.

Comment: @MaxMustermann Here's another perspective, written by an expert in my field: Lambek, J. "If Hamilton Had Prevailed: Quaternions in Physics." Mathematical Conversations. Springer, New York, NY, 2001. 259-274.

Answer (score -1):

Well, at first glance quaternions do not usually represent vectors, but unit quaternions represent rotation matrices, with multiplication of quaternions being something like a matrix product. Quaternions form an algebra, i.e. the important operations one can do with them are addition, multiplication with real numbers, and multiplication of quaternions.

Of course, they form a 4d vector space, so anything you can do with those you can also do here. There are generalizations of cross and dot product to any dimension (scalar product and wedge product), but they do not depend on the extra structure, i.e. the multiplication, quaternions have. Therefore these probably aren't what you are interested in.

Also, quaternions form a division ring, so that one can define left and right vector spaces over quaternions. One can also define scalar and wedge products on those, and I do think that would give an interesting theory, since there is much more structure here than on modules over arbitrary commutative rings. Maybe the most interesting way for you to go would be this direction, i.e. learn a bit about Euklidean and unitary vector spaces, tensor products, exterior algebras and how this can be generalized to modules over rings.